# Do they have the same meaning?

Tags: expressions, sentence-meaning

Assume you earned a million dollars last year.

1. You've doubled the income of last year.
2. You've been twice the income of last year.
3. You've earned money twice as much as last year.
4. You've earned money twice more than last year.

Do they have the same meaning that you've earned two million dollars now?
Which is most commonly used?

Comment: **1** is a non sequitur since what one "earned" isn't necessarily equal to one's "income" in that same period, financially speaking, so by switching from discussing what you "earned" to discussing your "income," you create a non sequitur, and since "the" is syntactically or semantically incorrect in a scenario where you are talking about yourself and *your* income. **2**, **3**, and **4** are all syntactically, semantically, and/or grammatical incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Benjamin Harman commented, none of your suggested sentences truly mean what you want them to mean and most of them don't even make sense grammatically.

> 1. You've doubled the income of last year.

What is "the" income? Your income, your family's income, your business's income? Also, the "...of last year" construction isn't idiomatic. Instead: **You doubled last year's income**—or, to address the specificity question, **You doubled your last year's income.**

> 2. You've been twice the income of last year.

A person is not an income. This sentence does not make sense. Try: **You have twice as much income as you did last year.**

> 3. You've earned money twice as much as last year.

Almost there but not quite. The word order sounds awkward. It should be: **You've earned twice as much money as last year.** You'll note this sentence looks very much like the one above; the difference is whether you're discussing *earned* income (from regular employment, contracting work, eBay sales, etc) or *total* income, which may include *unearned* income (stock dividends or gains from stock sales, legal settlements, etc).

> 4. You've earned money twice more than last year.

As written, this sounds like you're talking about the number of times you have earned income in the year—this year you did it on two more occasions than you did last year. This doesn't really make sense because "earning money" is usually a continuous activity, not a discrete one. It might be possible to talk this way about a performer, for example, who performed 30 times last year and 32 times this year, but that's a stretch.

---

In addition, using the present perfect "You have earned" is not necessarily wrong in this context, but I would use the simple past "You earned" instead.